# Data not saving in local database on re run c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, localdb

I've created a basic windows form application using the **Service-based Database** option so that when I deploy it on another pc it will not require to install sql server there.[image: Here is the image of my app]

I've added a LINQ-to-SQL class in the project and [here](https://codeshare.io/2W8Wg8) is my full code

And here is the app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="_16Sep18_databaseAppWithSetup_.Properties.Settings.WrestlersConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Wrestlers.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The problem is when every time I run my program the previously stored data is no longer in the database but when I input data and perform the insert,delete,update etc operations it works and the data is shown in the datagridview also but once I close the app all those data are gone.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: How are you determining the database is not being uploaded?  I suspect you are using SQL Server Management Studio to check that data wasn't changed.  The issue is with your connection string.  Your program is modifying a different database.   NEVER use the mdf filename in the connection string.  It is not needed.  The database has the file attached and is the owner of the file.   Then use Database=myDataBase in connection string to specify which database on the server you are using.  You can check the mdf file that the server is using by right click on database and check properties.

Comment: @jdweng can you write the whole connection string in the comments or in an answer...I don't understand what you are trying to say by **use Database=myDataBase in connection string**?

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  Use actual database name.

Comment: @jdweng my database name is Wrestlers.mdf so I tried connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Wrestlers.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: but I'm getting the error **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll** and **Additional information: Cannot open database "Wrestlers.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed**

Comment: Do not use the mdf file name.  The database name is the one in the SQL Server Manager without the mdf.  The database attached the mdf file and you do not need the mdf.  Just the actual attached database name.

Comment: @jdweng now I'm getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: Cannot open database "Wrestlers" requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: it is showing error in the line **dataGridView1.DataSource = x;** in the `loaddata()`

Comment: You are connecting to the database but not getting any data.  x is null.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and make sure there is data in the database/table.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because the mdf file is saving in DEBUG folder also when you try to run the program... 
Just go to app.config file,, 
it seems like you have added the directory like

Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

change the |DataDirectory| to full data directory address like

"AttachDbFileName=c:\Project\Data\Database1.mdf"

it will work

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by changing "copy always" => "copy if newer":

[image]

It worked for me. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The MDF file is copied to the debug folder on each run, and that is the file your code manipulates, not the one in your source folder.

Comment: So how do I fix the problem I'm having?

Comment: You could use a full path to the file during development

Comment: And what about during deployment?